# Filtering Array to return subset of elements in .Net 2.0

Tags: .net, vb.net, arrays, linq, .net-2.0

I have the following in a .Net 2.0 app:

```
Private chequeColl() As Cheque
For i = 0 To m.Length - 2
  chequeColl(i) = New Cheque()
  chequeColl(i).Id = Start_Mp + i
  chequeColl(i).Status = m(i)
Next
```

I now want to make chequeColl only contain those items where Status is not equal to 41.  In LINQ this would be easy but I can't think how to do it.

I cannot use the .Net 2.0 LINQ bridge products, I have to do this the old school way. At the end of it chequeColl must only contain those items that are not status of 41. I cannot have empty elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private chequeCollCleansed() as Cheque
Private count as int = 0
For i = 0 To chequeColl.Length
 If chequeColl[i].Status != 41 Then 
  chequeCollCleansed(count) = chequeColl[i]
  count = count + 1
 End If
Next
Set chequeColl = chequeCollCleansed
```

Please excuse my Basic, treat as pseudo code!

**edit** having seen the generics suggestion i now realise how old skool this is!

Answer (score 3):

If it's .Net 2.0, you can use generics.
How about putting your collection in a `List<T>` and then using `FindAll`?

Here's [a pretty good example](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/uploadfile/camurphy/vb.netlists11142006230335pm/vb.netlists.aspx) that walks through it for you.

And here's [another](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/genericlist.htm), longer one.

The essence of the first example (you should really read the article):

```
Public Class Person

Public age As Integer
Public name As String

Public Sub New(ByVal age As Integer, ByVal name As String)
    Me.age = age
    Me.name = name
End Sub 'New
End Class 'Person

List<person>people = new List<person>();
people.Add(New Person(50, "Fred"))
people.Add(New Person(30, "John"))
people.Add(New Person(26, "Andrew"))
people.Add(New Person(24, "Xavier"))
people.Add(New Person(5, "Mark"))
people.Add(New Person(6, "Cameron"))

'' Find the young
List<person> young = people.FindAll(delegate(Person p) { return p.age < 25; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't add them in the first place:

```
Private chequeColl() As Cheque
For i = 0 To m.Length - 2
  If m(i) !=  41 Then
    chequeColl(i) = New Cheque()
    chequeColl(i).Id = Start_Mp + i
    chequeColl(i).Status = m(i)
  End If
Next
```